# Adding datepicker to each newly added row

Tags: jquery

Here I am trying to add datepicker to the newly added rows but the same is not reflecting. Tried using the clone(true) function but no help.

The below code shows four columns and the first one being a date field.
Have to replicate the date picker to the newly added rows also.

```
$<html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Expenses</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
          <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
          <script>
          $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

          });
          function addRow(tableID) 
          {

                  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

                  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
                  var counts = rowCount - 1;

                  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                  var expense_date = document.createElement("input");
                  expense_date.type = "text";
                  expense_date.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].expense_date";
                  cell1.appendChild(expense_date);

                  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                  var expense_against = document.createElement("input");
                  expense_against.type = "text";
                  expense_against.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].expense_against";
                  cell2.appendChild(expense_against);

                  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                  var amount = document.createElement("input");
                  amount.type = "text";
                  amount.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].amount";
                  cell3.appendChild(amount);

                  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                  var paid_by = document.createElement("input");
                  paid_by.type = "text";
                  paid_by.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].paid_by";
                  cell4.appendChild(paid_by);

          }
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>
         <form action="submit" method="post">

        <p align ="center"><font size = "6" face = "Cursive">Expenses</font></p>

        <TABLE id="expensesTable" border="2" style="width:39%" align="center">
                <TR>
                        <TD align = "center"><font size = "4" face = "Cursive">EXPENSE_DATE</font></TD>
                        <TD align = "center"><font size = "4" face = "Cursive">EXPENSE_AGAINST</font></TD>
                        <TD align = "center"><font size = "4" face = "Cursive">AMOUNT</font></TD>
                        <TD align = "center"><font size = "4" face = "Cursive">PAID_BY</font></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                        <TD><INPUT type="text" id="datepicker" name="expenses[0].expense_date" /></TD>
                        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="expenses[0].expense_against" /></TD>
                        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="expenses[0].amount" /></TD>
                        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="expenses[0].paid_by" /></TD>

                </TR>
        </TABLE> 

        </div>
        <p align ="center">
        <INPUT type="button" value="Add More" name="expenses[0].more" onclick="addRow('expensesTable')" />
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
        </p>
        </form>



        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the datepicker after the element is appended, like below.

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var counts = rowCount - 1;

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var expense_date = document.createElement("input");
    expense_date.type = "text";
    expense_date.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].expense_date";
    cell1.appendChild(expense_date);

    //add this line.
    $('input[name="' + expense_date.name + '"]').datepicker();

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var expense_against = document.createElement("input");
    expense_against.type = "text";
    expense_against.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].expense_against";
    cell2.appendChild(expense_against);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var amount = document.createElement("input");
    amount.type = "text";
    amount.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].amount";
    cell3.appendChild(amount);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var paid_by = document.createElement("input");
    paid_by.type = "text";
    paid_by.name = "expenses[" + counts + "].paid_by";
    cell4.appendChild(paid_by);

}
```

Comment: @SaiBharath try `$('input[name="' + expense_date.name + '"]').datepicker();`, if that doesn't work, it means that your inputs have same name in both rows. So datepicker works only the first one with that name..

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is to call the `datepicker()` AFTER the rows are added to the page. This means that every single time you add a new row you have to initialize the plugin on that same row.

Comment: With the above combination of the added line and your suggestion to keep the datepicker after the fuction it worked.. thanx a ton :)